The $L^2$ operator not returning the expected value (2) when applied on the (2,1,0) Hydrogen wave function
Let the Hydrogen wave function for the state $n=2, l=1, m=0$ be described as:
$$\psi_{210} =cos(\sigma )*f(r)$$
Since the squared angular momentum eigenvalue is $L^2=l(l+1)$, I would expect it to be 2 for the $\psi_{210}$ state, so, $L^2|\psi_{210}\rangle=2\psi_{210}$.
Let the gradient in spherical coordinates be:
$$\triangledown = \widehat{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r}\widehat{\theta }\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta} + \frac{1}{r*sin(\theta)}\widehat{\varphi }\frac{\partial }{\partial \varphi}$$
Since this state that is not dependent on $\varphi$, $L^2$ gets reduced basically to:
$$L^2|\psi_{210}\rangle = i^2r^2 \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2  }{\partial \theta }\psi = 1*\psi_{210}$$
Therefore, the eigenstate for $L^2$ in the (2,1,0) state is 1, while it should be 2.
On the other hand, if I project the $\psi_{210z}$ state on the X and Y axis and then apply the $L^2_x$ and $L^2_y$ operators to the corresponding axis, I get that the amplitudes for the projected states are:
$$\langle\psi_{210z}|\psi_{21\pm 1x}\rangle = \langle\psi_{210z}|\psi_{21\pm 1y}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
Therefore, the obtained value obtained projecting the state for each direction is:
$$ L^2= L^2_z+L^2_x+L^2_y= 0 + (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2*2*2=2 $$
So, by applying the projections I get the expected value, however, when I apply the $L^2$ value on the $\psi_{210z}$ state I obtain an unexpected value. I do not understand why this is happening. The $L^2_z$ eigenstates are also $L^2$ eigenstates so I think it should not be needed to project it to the other coordinates.

Your $L^2$ operator is just wrong. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates

What is $\sigma$ in your first equation?

As already mentioned in the comments, the expression for $L^2$ used in the question is incorrect. Somewhat to my surprise, it is not easy to find a reference to the correct one (at least not doing a quick search...) The Wikipedia page in the comment does not explicitly give it, and it is also not in other places where you would normally look, like Jackson's [front] and [back] pages.
But a quick derivation, keeping just the angle-dependent part of $-\nabla^2$, shows us that it actually is the following:
$$L^2\ f(\theta,\varphi)=\Big(-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}
-\cot\theta\, \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}
 - \frac1{\sin^2\theta}\  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial\varphi^2}\Big)\ f(\theta,\varphi)
$$
which means of course that in absence of $\varphi$-dependence:
$$L^2\ f(\theta)=\Big(-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}
-\cot\theta\, \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}
\Big)\ f(\theta)
$$
and for a function like you have, where all the angle dependence is just $\cos\theta$, this correctly gives the expected eigenvalue $2$.
EDIT PS: I now see that another wikipedia page, at the end, after you skip everything they have to say about it, actually does give the expression: [Wikipedia].
